# How to pronounce the bi- prefix

Tags: pronunciation

"bi" is a prefix [means two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqHKxUGY2zI). It seems in mostly is pronounced as /bʌɪ/ like bicentennial /bʌɪsɛnˈtɛnɪəl/ and some times as /bɪ/ e.g. binocular /bɪˈnɒkjʊlə/ or bigamy /'bɪgəmɪ/.

Any tips or rules to help to pronounce this prefix correctly? I think if I have a list of all words with /bɪ/ I can memorise too.

Comment: As an American, I pronounce "binoculars" like the first group; only "bigamy" is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used [Regex Dictionary](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/) to bring up a list of all words starting with "bi" and read through them.

Of these, for cases where the prefix "bi-" is used with the meaning of "two"/"twice", /bʌɪ/ was always the correct pronunciation, with very few exceptions. The only exceptions I noticed were "billion" (+billionaire, billionth etc.), "bigamy", and "binocular" - although as @randomhead noted, /bʌɪˈnɒkjʊlər/ is acceptable in American English. So it is probably easiest just to memorize the very few exceptions. It's possible that I missed others, but I read through reasonably carefully.

Of course, there are lots of other words who do not start with the "bi-" = "two" prefix, but which happen to start with the letters "bi" (bill, big, bias, binder...); pronunciation of these words is less predictable. Luckily, it is usually pretty obvious if you know the meaning of the word whether the "bi-" = "two" prefix is being used. One to watch out for is "bikini", which you might assume uses this prefix, but which actually has a different etymology and is pronounced /bɪ/.